# What is the value of $\cos(\tan^{-1}(\tan 2))$?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse, inverse-function

What is the value of $\cos(\tan^{-1}(\tan 2))$?

Am I thinking correct? $\tan 2$ is negative so $\tan^{-1}$ and $-\tan 2$ cancel each other giving $\cos(-2)$ which finally gives the answer as $-\cos 2$? Am I correct? Please explain if not.

Comment: Where does $-\cos$ come from?

Comment: Now the question is finally correctly edited. Please have a look and explain.

Comment: Cosine is not an odd function, it is even. However the final answer is correct (i.e. $-\cos (2)$).

Comment: @Ujjwal  Please check that my edits did not change the meaning of your post.  Also, please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: $\cos(-x) = \cos(x) \forall x$

Answer (score 2):

$\arctan \tan x\equiv x\mod\pi$ and by definition, $\arctan t\in(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$. As $\;\frac\pi 2<2<\pi$, this means $\arctan \tan 2=2-\pi$, whence
$$\cos(\arctan \tan 2)=\cos(2-\pi)=\color{red}{-\cos 2}.$$

Comment: What do you mean by "arctantanx≡x mod π"

Comment: They differ by an integer multiple of $\pi$. That is a standard congruence.

Comment: What do you mean by differ exactly? Please explain by an example

Comment: Clear and concise!   +1 -Mark

Comment: @Ujjwal: The congruence class of $2$ is the set $\bigl\{2,2+\pi,2+2\pi,\dots,2-\pi, 2-2\pi,\dots\bigr\}$. All these values have tangent equal to $\tan 2$.